# How to interface function of deployed contract in new contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens

I have deployed Standard token contract using mist. Now I want to create interface functions for the deployed contract.

```
contract MyToken {
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner returns (bool);
}

contract NewContract {

    Mytoken token;

    uint256 public rate;

    function NewContract(uint256 _rate){
        rate = _rate;
    }

    function () payable {
        token.mint(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

First issue is I can't create interface for those functions that have some custom modifiers attached i.e `onlyOwner`. If I remove the modifer `onlyOwner`, I am able to deploy using mist, but when I transfer some amount to this contract it throws `callback contain no result Gas required exceeds limit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommended way is to have `mint()` function in token contract and I don't see any issue with that.

**First part of your question:** You can call `onlyOwner` function by preserving `msg.sender` and can be achieved by using [delegatecall](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html?highlight=delegatecall).

**Second Part:** Your code is not working even after removing modifier because you have to initialize the object of `Mytoken` with the address of the token contract that is already deployed on blockchain like:

```
    contract MyToken {
        function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) returns (bool);
    }
    contract NewContract {

        Mytoken token;

        uint256 public rate;

        function NewContract(uint256 _rate,address _tokenAddress){
           token = Mytoken(_tokenAddress);
           rate = _rate;
        }
        function () payable {
            token.mint(msg.sender, msg.value);
        }
    }
```

Above code will work if you remove  `onlyOwner` modifier from `mint()` function.