# Accessing Deployed Token methods (containing modifiers) from a Separate Crowdsale contract

Tags: solidity, ico, crowdsale, tokens

Is it possible to deploy the Token contract (T) & CrowdSale contract (S) separately and still be possible to access (T)'s modifier protected methods from (S).

**Code of (T)**

```
 contract Token {
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint returns (bool) {
     totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);
     balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
     Mint(_to, _amount);
     return true;
 }
```

**Code of (S)**

```
contract SellToken {
  TokenInstance instance;
  function SellToken(address _address) {
    instance = TokenInstance(_address);
  }

  function () payable { 
    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(rate);

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    instance.mint(beneficiary, tokens);
  }

}
```

For some reason, when i'm trying to send ether to (B) I get the following error

[image: Transaction cannot be processed]

EDIT: I also tried the method of having an Abstract interface but that didn't seem to have much luck either (Ref: [Stack exchange Post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20798/how-to-interface-function-of-deployed-contract-in-new-contract/20818#20818))

**Abstract Interface**

```
contract TokenAbstractInterface {
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) returns (bool);
    function finishMinting() returns (bool);
}
```

**Modified Code of (S)**

```
contract SellToken {
  TokenAbstractInterface instance;
  function SellToken(address _address) {
    instance = TokenAbstractInterface(_address);
  }

  function () payable { 
    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(rate);

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    instance.mint(beneficiary, tokens);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the full code is hard to be sure. But the function `mint` in Token as `onlyOwner` modifier.

```
function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint returns (bool)
```

This usually implies that only the owner of the token can call `mint` function, if you want.

If you want to mint token from SellToken you have to set SellToken as the owner of Token contract.

Comment: Yes you were right on this. I had to transfer the Token's ownership to the Smart contract. I also had to add a method to retransfer the Token ownership from the Smart contract to any other account as to not get locked out when the crowdsale gets over.